# Copying data from one entity to another entity, while core data migration

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

I have following data structure :

1. "TestUserData" entity (in core data model version_1 **which is already shipped**)

   - userName
   - age
   - gender

Now I need to make some changes in core data, So I increased model version to 2 and I created a new entity "RegisteredUser" with following details :

1. "RegisteredUser" entity (in core data model version_2)

   - firstName
   - lastName
   - userCode

Now I need to migrate core data model version_1 to version_2 and also need to copy data of "TestUserData" entity to "RegisteredUser" entity.

Right now I am using "1To2MappingModel.xcmappingmodel" file(generated by xcode) to migrate, which just does the migration.

But how do I copy data from one entity to another entity plus splitting userName in firstName and lastName.

Any pointers on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.

**Note** : It can be done by manually copying data after the migration is done, but I think there would be some way of doing the same while migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice article on [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html) that contains an example.

Comment: Thanks man, though I didn't use it but at least I get the idea that I will have to write script to copy data.